# Expository materials on slow-fast Hamiltonian system

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I am looking for expository materials on slow-fast Hamiltonian systems that are accessible to non-mathematicians. Crudely speaking, I encountered from my research a slow-fast system with the following feature: if we linearize its equation of motion near some mechanical equilibrium position $x^\ast$, we yield an equation of motion of the form $\ddot{y} = -Ay$, where $y=x-x^{\ast}$. $A$ is a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix that depends on $x^\ast$. The nullity of the matrix $A$ is 1 (i.e. only one direction along which the motion is slow) for all mechanical equilibria except for a few specific points $\{x^\ast_i\}$, where the nullity jumps to 2. Therefore, the subspace where the slow variables live in contains singular points. I hope the folks here may point me toward some potentially useful references.

Comment: What is the dimension of your full system - is it in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? Then the nullity must be even. @Isidore Seville